QModbusDevice state does not reflect real connection status
I'm writing a module that interacts with Modbus controllers. The problem is that once a QModbusDevice has reached ConnectedState, the state does not change. Here's a minimal example code I've written:
#include <QDebug>
#include <QModbusTcpClient>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QModbusTcpClient client;
  QObject::connect(&client, &QModbusDevice::stateChanged, &a,
                   [&client](auto const &state) {
                     qDebug() << "State changed" << state;
                     if (QModbusDevice::UnconnectedState == state)
                       client.connectDevice();
                   });
  client.setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::NetworkPortParameter, 502);
  client.setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::NetworkAddressParameter,
                                "192.168.8.6");
  client.setTimeout(500);
  client.setNumberOfRetries(5);
  client.connectDevice();

  return a.exec();
}

192.168.8.6 is my laptop with Qt's Modbus server example running on it, and I'm testing interaction by enabling/disabling WiFi on that laptop. When WiFi is not enabled, interaction goes as expected:
State changed QModbusDevice::ConnectingState
State changed QModbusDevice::UnconnectedState
State changed QModbusDevice::ConnectingState
State changed QModbusDevice::UnconnectedState

Then I enable WiFi and receive the following output:
State changed QModbusDevice::ConnectingState
State changed QModbusDevice::ConnectedState

And after that no state changes occur. I disable and enable WiFi, yet the QModbusDevice doesn't go into Unconnected state as I expect it to do.
As the workarounds I'm thinking about manually disconnecting of QModbusDevice or even destroying of the device, but this would complicate my program's behavior a lot. Is there a way of making QModbusDevice really change its state when the device doesn't reply within a set timeout for a set number of retries?

This is a known problem with TCP. You do not know the connection has been lost until you try to send something or you hit a timeout.

This question is similar to: Detecting TCP Client Disconnect (admittedly your question is re Modbus, but it's still a TCP connection - see the SO-KEEPALIVE section of the spec). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Brits, the question is not exactly similar to the one you refer to. First difference is that QModbusTcpClient is a client and not a server. And the second difference is that I'm not writing my own implementation of Modbus protocol (in which case I could implement SO_KEEPALIVE in a way I wanted), but rather using an implementation written by Qt. So my question is more like "Does the QModbus module implement SO_KEEPALIVE?" I appreciate your link to the specs, though, it seems quite useful.

@KirillDidkovsky my comment aimed to explain why you are seeing what you are (sorry - I can't help with QT code). However rereading the question you say "when the device doesn't reply within a set timeout..." so are you continuing to poll the device after dropping the wifi? (if so I would expect you to receive an error, including that bit of code might help get an answer).

@Brits, the code where I set the number of retries and the timeout is already in the example:
client.setTimeout(500);
client.setNumberOfRetries(5);
It's logical to expect the class aimed at providing connection to the Modbus device and having number of retries and timeout explicitly set to change its state when the connection is broken.
I've implemented a workaround - I send other packets (reading DI and DO state) and start a timer on each packet sent, and when I have more than a given number of timeouts I break the connection. But I did expect QModbusDevice to do this for me.

@KirillDidkovsky I would expect the state to change if you make a Modbus request after disconnecting/reconnecting the wifi (the loss of connection should be detected when an attempt is made to use the link). The timeout/retries only apply when a request is made (not when the link is idle). Sending the other packets on a timer sounds like a good option (but I would not expect you to need to set your own timer for this, you are right in that the library should inform you when the connection state change is detected).
